# getting double value from group concact

Tags: sql

I am having a problem where I am getting duplicated values from what I think I should be getting.

here is my sql:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT p.products_image,
                pd.products_name,
                p.products_id,
                p.products_model,
                p.manufacturers_id,
                m.manufacturers_name,
                p.products_price,
                p.products_sort_order,
                p.products_tax_class_id,
                pd.products_viewed,
                group_concat(p2i.icons_id separator ",") AS icon_ids,
                group_concat(pi.icon_class separator ",") AS icon_class,
                IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) AS specials_new_products_price,
                IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) AS final_price
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN specials s ON p.products_id = s.products_id
LEFT JOIN manufacturers m ON p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id
JOIN products_description pd ON p.products_id = pd.products_id
JOIN products_to_categories p2c ON p.products_id = p2c.products_id
INNER JOIN products_specifications ps7 ON p.products_id = ps7.products_id
LEFT JOIN products_to_icon p2i ON p.products_id = p2i.products_id
LEFT JOIN products_icons pi ON p2i.icons_id = pi.icons_id
WHERE p.products_status = '1'
  AND pd.language_id = '1'
  AND ps7.specification IN ('Polycotton' ,
                            'Reflective')
  AND ps7.specifications_id = '7'
  AND ps7.language_id = '1'
  AND p2c.categories_id = '21'
GROUP BY p.products_id
ORDER BY p.products_sort_order
```

The column that is getting double values is icon_ids from the group concact. This seams to happen only if ploycotton, and reflective are both IN ps7.specification.

If it is only one or the other then it works fine.

The products_to_icon table contains 2 columns, products_id and icons_id.

If a product has 2 icons, there are 2 rows so I'm pretty sure it is this fact that is causing the duplicate icons ids.

When I run this, the icon_ids column for a product with 2 icons is "4,4,6,6" for example, when what I need is "4,6"

Answer (score 0):

can be something stupid but for what I can read from your query. I tried with some dummy data,

```
GROUP_CONCAT(`icon` )   product
icon1,icon1             Test1
icon2                   Test2
icon3                   Test3


SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `icon` ) , product
FROM  `Test1` 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY  `product` 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This is working fine and I'm querying a table that looks like this:

```
product icon
Test1   icon1
Test1   icon1
Test2   icon2
Test3   icon3
```

This is the result if I add another line Test1 icon2

```
GROUP_CONCAT(`icon` )   product
icon1,icon1,icon2   Test1
icon2   Test2
icon3   Test3
```

I Forgot the point, :) basically I think that your query idea is correct, but for some reason you have a duplicate (possibly some join or grouping error that is duplicating the rows). Try to run the query without aggregation, and see if actually there are more lines than expected.